# How long does the hide action last?

Tags: dnd-5e, stealth

Does the character's "action" take each round to maintain the ambush action used in the first turn?

This question arose as a consequence of the fact that every other "Action" is valid for a maximum of 1 round

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate, which is okay! If you think your question does differ, please let us know how and the community can determine how to handle.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to find a similar question, but I didn't find it

Comment: I actually searched on google for it :)